# Two left shift operations got different answers

Tags: c++

```
int main() {

   int n = 32;
   cout << (-1 << n) << ' ' << (-1 << 32);
}
```

I'm using Viusal Studio 2013 and output is

```
-1 0
```

Why do I get different results for the two operations, even though I shift the same number by 32 in both cases?

Comment: Okay, they got different answers. And what is your question?

Comment: @NickyC Isn't it obvious? They look like they should give the same answer.

Comment: @SchighSchagh It was to ask for an explicit question statement, which might improve the question, and which did not exist at the time. Besides, some may not recognize the obvious question since the undefined behaviour may be too obvious for them to be a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the warnings during compilation, you get:

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
cout << (-1 << n) << " " << (-1 << 32);
```

In the first case, `n`, the compiler does not know the value of `n` at compile time, but it does for `32`.

---

According to the doc:

> The result of a shift operation **is undefined if additive-expression is negative or if additive-expression is greater than or equal to the number of bits in the (promoted) shift-expression.** No shift operation is performed if additive-expression is 0.
>
> If you left-shift a signed number so that the sign bit is affected, the result is undefined. The following example shows what happens in Visual C++ when a 1 bit is left-shifted into the sign bit position.

Comment: I get it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the post as answered with the checkmark on the left. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Shift operations are only defined up to widths less than the width of the integral type. Your program therefore invokes undefined behaviour and the output is meaningless.